# What does epoll do with a file descriptor that refers to a directory?

Tags: linux, file-descriptor, epoll

Just like the title says, it I register a file descriptor that is a directory with epoll, what does it do?

Comment: If you want to monitor file system events on Linux, use [`inotify`](http://linux.die.net/man/7/inotify).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Nothing** -- the call to register the fd will (at least for common Linux filesystems) fail with `EPERM`.

I tested this using the following demo program:

```
#include <sys/epoll.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int ep = epoll_create1(0);
    int fd = open("/tmp", O_RDONLY|O_DIRECTORY);
    struct epoll_event evt = {
        .events = EPOLLIN
    };

    if (ep < 0 || fd < 0) {
        printf("Error opening fds.\n");
        return -1;
    }

    if (epoll_ctl(ep, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, fd, &evt) < 0) {
        perror("epoll_ctl");
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

With the following result:

```
[nelhage@hectique:/tmp]$ make epoll
cc     epoll.c   -o epoll
[nelhage@hectique:/tmp]$ ./epoll
epoll_ctl: Operation not permitted
```

To figure out what was going on here, I went to the source. I [happen to know](http://www.quora.com/Network-Programming/How-is-epoll-implemented) that most of the behavior of `epoll` is determined by the `->poll` function on the `struct file_operations` corresponding to the target file, which depends on the file system in question. I picked `ext4` as a typical example, and looked at `fs/ext4/dir.c`, which [defines](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/fs/ext4/dir.c#L622) `ext4_dir_operations` as follows:

```
const struct file_operations ext4_dir_operations = {
    .llseek     = ext4_dir_llseek,
    .read       = generic_read_dir,
    .readdir    = ext4_readdir,
    .unlocked_ioctl = ext4_ioctl,
#ifdef CONFIG_COMPAT
    .compat_ioctl   = ext4_compat_ioctl,
#endif
    .fsync      = ext4_sync_file,
    .release    = ext4_release_dir,
};
```

Note the lack of a `.poll` definition, meaning it will be initialized to `NULL`. So, swinging back to epoll, which is defined in `fs/eventpoll.c`, we look for checks for `poll` being NULL, and we find one [early on](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v3.5/fs/eventpoll.c#L1709) in the `epoll_ctl` syscall definition:

```
/* The target file descriptor must support poll */
error = -EPERM;
if (!tfile->f_op || !tfile->f_op->poll)
    goto error_tgt_fput;
```

As our test indicated, if the target file doesn't support `poll`, the insert attempt will just fail out with `EPERM`.

It's possible that other filesystems define `.poll` methods on their directory file objects, but I doubt that many do.

Comment: Is `dirfd(opendir("/tmp"))` preferred over `open(path, O_RDONLY|O_DIRECTORY);`? Just a style question. Using `opendir` doesn't magically make the fs support poll.

Comment: `dirfd(opendir("..."))` is more portable, so is probably preferred in general. I'm a Linux kernel hacker, so I personally tend to default to using the system-call interface even when it's not the most appropriate, because I know it better. Obviously here it doesn't really matter, since `epoll` is also Linux specific.